# compare the latitude and longitude of the user's to the one in the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, location

so i would like  to create a system where we get the users latitude and longitude and compare it with the ones in the MySQL database to know if the users are located in those location or not. i managed to get the user's latitude and longitude but i would like a function to compare them with the ones i stored in my database. these are the code i used to get the location in my control

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class HealthController extends Controller
{
     public function showHealth(Request $request)
        {
        $ip = $request->ip;
        $data = Location::get($ip);

        return view ('healthcode',compact('data'));
        }
}
```

and my migration:

```
{
        Schema::create('healthcode', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('place');
            $table->string('latitude')->nullable();
            $table->string('longitude')->nullable();
        });
```

i do have the function to collect the coordinates from the database which is:

```
Healthcode::where('latitude' => $data['latitude'])
    ->where('longitude' => $data['longitude'])
    ->exists();
```

i would just like to get a function to compare the actual user's location to the ones in the database.

Comment: But the LatLng can fluctuate even within few centimeters of displacement. How can you compare these? You should calculate the distance between the current LatLng and the Existing LatLng in the DB to calculate the safe distance and measure whether the user is in the perimeter of the location.

Comment: @SKR then can you help me make a function to compare if the user is in the perimeter? i'm really  having a hard time on that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have used in one of my previous project.

```
function getDistance(
  $latFrom,
  $lngFrom,
  $latTo,
  $lngTo,
  $earthRadius = 6371000
) {
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($lngFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($lngTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));

  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

After you get the distance, you should calculate how much threshold you can consider as the user is within the perimeter of the campus or the location.

Comment: can you just put the steps in detail please .... if the last step is to calculate the threshold can you please add it